# A Mindmap with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, mindmaps

I want to create a mindmap by using the following. I have never created a mindmap before.

I want to use `\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}`
But I think that I have a lot of things about this.

**Question 1:** Could you help me for creating a good mindmap (trees, or another style)?

**Question 2:** How can we do the picture in text width?

**Main node:** AREAS

**Child nodes are:**

1. Signal processing
   i)Discrete
   ii)Continous
2. Computer vision i)Data ii)Compressing
3. Communication Engineering
4. Biotechnology and bioinformatics
5. Biomedical engineering
6. Data analysis
7. Management
8. Electrical engineering
9. Instrumentation & Control
10. Transportation
11. Civil engineering
12. Astronomy
13. Wavelet Networks
14. Fractal analysis
15. Numerical Analysis
    i)ODEs
    ii)PDEs
    iii) Integral Equations

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\begin{document}

    
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
                        mindmap,
                        concept color=yellow
                        ] 
    \node[concept] {AREAS}
        [clockwise from=10]
         child [concept color=pink]{node[concept] {Signal processing} }
          child [concept color=pink]{node[concept] {Computer vision} }
            child [concept color=pink]{node[concept] {Communication Engineering} }
            child [concept color=pink]{node[concept] {Biotechnology and bioinformatics } }
            child [concept color=pink]{node[concept] { Biomedical engineering} }
            child[concept color=orange!80] {node[concept] {Data Analysis}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Your code it is not compilable. Please, can you edit it?

Comment: Why isn't `AREAS` your first node and what do you mean by 'smart'?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. The post was edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following might help getting you started. However, the font sizes in the child nodes are extremely small, so maybe using an enumerated list as you did in your question is a better way to present this information in a more legible way:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
                    mindmap,
                    concept color=yellow, 
                    level 1 concept/.append style=
                      {every child/.style={concept color=pink, 
                                           font=\scriptsize, 
                                           minimum size=0pt,
                                           text width=1.75cm},
                       sibling angle=-24},
                     level 2 concept/.append style=
                      {every child/.style={concept color=pink, 
                                           font=\tiny, 
                                           minimum size=0pt,
                                           text width=1.25cm},
                       sibling angle=-30}
                   ] 
    \node[concept] {AREAS}
        [clockwise from=-90]
         child{node[concept] {\hspace{0pt}Signal processing} 
             [clockwise from=-100] child {node[concept] {\hspace{0pt}Discrete}}
             child {node[concept] {\hspace{0pt}Continous}}}
         child{node[concept] {\hspace{0pt}Computer vision} 
             [clockwise from=-80] child {node[concept] {\hspace{0pt}Data}}
             child {node[concept] {\hspace{0pt}Compressing}}
             }
         child{node[concept] {\hspace{0pt}Communication Engineering} }
         child{node[concept] {\hspace{0pt}Biotechnology and bioinformatics } }
         child{node[concept] {\hspace{0pt}Biomedical engineering} }
         child{node[concept] {\hspace{0pt}Data Analysis}}
         child{node[concept] {\hspace{0pt}Management}}
         child{node[concept] {\hspace{0pt}Electrical engineering}}
         child{node[concept] {\hspace{0pt}Instrumentation \& Control}}
         child{node[concept] {\hspace{0pt}Transportation}}
         child{node[concept] {\hspace{0pt}Civil engineering}}
         child{node[concept] {\hspace{0pt}Astronomy}}
         child{node[concept] {\hspace{0pt}Wavelet Networks}}
         child{node[concept] {\hspace{0pt}Fractal analysis}}
         child{node[concept] {\hspace{0pt}Numerical Analysis} 
             [clockwise from=200] child {node[concept] {\hspace{0pt}ODEs}}
             child {node[concept] {\hspace{0pt}PDEs}}
             child {node[concept] {\hspace{0pt}Integral Equations}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}      

\end{document}
```